# ConfusionMatrix table in Julia

Tags: julia, confusion-matrix

I would like to make a confusion matrix table in Julia of classification predictions to understand the FP, TP etc. The `ConfusionMatrix` output of the `EvalMetrics` package is not the output I want. Here is some reproducible code:

```
julia> using EvalMetrics
julia> targets = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
julia> predicts = [0,0,1,1,0,1,1]

julia> ConfusionMatrix(targets, predicts)
ConfusionMatrix{Int64}(4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2)
```

The output says 4 actual positives and 3 actual negatives like mentioned in [docs](https://docs.juliahub.com/EvalMetrics/nRVCq/0.2.0/). I don't like this output since I always have to look up what the values mean, so I prefer a table like this:

```
 predxact│ 0      1     
    ─────┼──────────────
       0 │     1      2
       1 │     2      2
```

So I was wondering if it possible to make a confusion matrix table in `Julia` like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping the code in the OP, we can pull out the matrix entries from the confusion matrix object:

```
using NamedArrays
using EvalMetrics

targets = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
predicts = [0,0,1,1,0,1,1]

cm = ConfusionMatrix(targets, predicts)

n = NamedArray(getproperty.(Ref(cm), [:tn :fn ; :fp :tp]), 
               (["f", "t"], ["f", "t"]), 
               ("pred", "true"))
```

Gives a named array which displays as follows:

```
2×2 Named Matrix{Int64}
pred ╲ true │ f  t
────────────┼─────
f           │ 1  2
t           │ 2  2
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative (styled for pretty-printing, you could avoid using DataFrames.jl and it would still work):

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> using FreqTables

julia> freqtable(DataFrame(targets = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1], predicts = [0,0,1,1,0,1,1]), :targets, :predicts)
2×2 Named Matrix{Int64}
targets ╲ predicts │ 0  1
───────────────────┼─────
0                  │ 1  2
1                  │ 2  2
```